# c++ nested class with 1 of the object as private

Tags: c++

I have two classes, for example class A and B. B is encapsulation in A under private;

```
class A
{
   private:
    int x;
    int y;
    B b;

    public:
           void set(int , int, int, int, int);
           void setX(int);
           void setY(int);
           string toString();
 };

void A::set(int high, int low, int middle)
{
   B(high, low, middle);
   setX(x);
   setY(y);

}


void A:: setX(int x)
{
this -> x = x;    
}

void A:: setY(int y)
{
    this -> y = y;
 }

string A::toString()
{

       string str;
   ostringstream convert;
   convert << getlow();
   str = convert.str();

return str;
}


class B
{
     private:
             int low;
             int middle;
             int hight;

     public:
            B();
            B(int, int, int);
            int getLow();
            int getMiddle();
            int getHigh();
};
```

in another class with my int main

```
int main ()
{
   int test1,test2,test3,test4,test5;

   // with lots of codes

   A a;
   a.set (test1,test2,test3,test4,test5);


}
```

When i get some values from int main, i pass in the 3 values into set, which initialize object B. when i use the getB function, all i get is values of 0, or it doesn't appear at all. (I have a constructor that takes in arguments and set all int to 0). Can someone enlighten me? And please do not tell me not to use this. I'm new to C++ so guide me along.

Comment: show B's code and main() as well. i dont see the functions having any return type. also, use const at the end of those member functions that don't change the object (such as getters)

Comment: This code will not compile for many reasons (no return types, confusing Class and instance names, etc.).  Please copy/paste directly from valid code.

Comment: Your methods are missing return types... You should really paste compilable code snippets, or if that compiles for you, then you should really enable warnings (-Wall -Wextra for gcc) and fix those, as the first thing. Or if you can't fix these, then ask about that, with the compiler messages (and lines they point to) included.

Comment: I'm sorry i've edited my codes.

Answer (score 1):

Change the definition of class A at least the following way

```
class A
{
    private:
             B b;
             int x;
             int y;

    public:
           void set(int, int, int);
           int getB();
 };

void A::set(int high, int low, int middle)
{
   b = B(high, low, middle);

}

int A::getB()
{

    return b.getLow();
}
```

Comment: omg how could i have missed that out. thank you so much. I feel so dumb right now

Answer (score 1):

in your set you don't initialize b member variable:

```
A::set(int high, int low, int middle)
{
   B(high, low, middle);
}
```